# Pass handle to stdin down pipeline

Tags: pipe, stdin, fifo

Say I have

```
node foo.js | node bar.js
```

is there a way to pass a handle on foo's stdin to bar?

I have a rare case where I'd like to communicate backwards in the pipeline.

At the least I know that I could send node bar.js the pid of node foo.js. Given that pid, on *nix, I should be able to write to foo's stdin using:

```
/proc/<pid>/fd/0
```

but is there a way to do the same on MacOS?

Comment: IMHO this is best asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: I did actually, I asked it about a week ago on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270986/pass-handle-down-pipeline

Comment: maybe I should start a bounty on it

Comment: `/proc/<pid>/fd/0` would get you a _handle_ on pid's stdin but what would you do with that? What if it's a terminal device, a regular file, a socket, a pipe? Here, it looks like you want `foo.js` stdin to be a pipe (or other IPC channel like a socketpair) and `bar.js` to have a file descriptor to the other end of that pipe.

Comment: It sounds very similar to your earlier [Communicate backwards in a pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/404286) question.

Comment: Yeah it's related to that question, at this point it's no longer a practical question, more of what-if

Comment: IMHO, your best bet would be via either a socket or named pipe

Comment: How can I use a socket without start a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case no, because the write handle of the stdin of `foo` is only in the hands of its parent process (`foo` only sees the read handle)... You have to set up a specific pipe (anonymous or FIFO) between the two; and this is better anyway because you don't know what would happen if `bar` wrote to that handle as the same time as `foo`'s parent.